# How to play video .avi or mp4 in ionic

Tags: angularjs, video, ionic-framework

I have some files in format .avi and mp4, but I need to play those video in ionic.

How to play those files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

crosswalk problem , I install these plugin:

ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview

and problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

Read through this: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

It is the same concept however I have not yet found out how to play video in background on both IOS and native so if you figure this out let me know.